# Phalcon - Composer install of Dev-Tools error: requested PHP extension -

Tags: composer-php, phalcon

**composer install** with file **compose.json**

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phalcon/devtools": "~3.4"
    }
}
```

should install Phalcon Dev-Tools.

Actual Behavior
Instead, it breaks with error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. 

Problem 1

Installation request for phalcon/devtools ~3.4 -> satisfiable by phalcon/devtools[v3.4.0].
phalcon/devtools v3.4.0 requires ext-phalcon ~3.3 -> the requested PHP extension phalcon is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini You can also run php --ini inside a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

**Details**
MacOS 10.13.5,
MAMP 4, PHP 7.2.1
php_phalcon.so 3.4 is copied into the extension directory and inserted into php.ini from php-phalcon-mamp

**proof:**

```
php -m 
phalcon
....
```

how to force update composer ignoring the dependencies?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase its clearly stated in the question "Problem". How to resolve the problem is in the answer this is knowledge sharing self Q&A style , if not helpful to anyone i can keep it on my notepad and delete this question

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out by running the below command.

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```